# How to download file as a pdf in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, download, pdf-generation, fs

my need is  on a click button, I need to get a pdf file from a directory and download as same pdf file in a browser.

I have a pdf file with 4-5 pages.

below is my code to read the pdf file I used *fs.createReadStream*

```
var fs = require('fs');

var data = '';

var readStream = fs.createReadStream('D:/Passbook.pdf', 'utf8');

readStream.on('data', function(chunk) {
    data += chunk;
}).on('end', function() {
    console.log(data);
});
```

here as a first step I would like to see the data for what I have fetched, but I the console log shows me something gibberish texts like below

```
ocProps/app.xmlPK-!t?9z�(CpcustomXml/_rels/item1.xml.relsPKIr

+100 lines
```

my plan is to if I can see the text then I would do *fs.writeFile* in pdf format, but I'm not sure whether it is possible to write a pdf file and it should be fetched and downloadable for user.

note - I'm using node version of **6.10.0**

Comment: "D:/Passbook.docx" you are not reading a pdf file?

Comment: its an typo.modified my question

Comment: Unrelated, but please update NodeJS